# Updating / writing to sqlite3 is extremely slow (using Python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a local SQLite database with about 5m rows (approx. 500mb).

It has the following schema:

```
index: integer
URL: text
date_added: text
date_updated: text
target: text
response_code: text
```

Now I am using the following query to update entries (simplified):

```
for result in results:
        c.execute("UPDATE websites SET target = ?, response_code = ?, date_updated = ? WHERE url = ?", (result[1], result[2], result[3], result[0]))
```

It works fine but is insanely slow (i.e., as it queries the entire database every time), making "just updating" my database the absolute bottleneck of my entire Python script.

What would you suggest to me to substantially increase the speed of writing to the database?

Making URL a primary key did not improve speed by a lot.

Should I instead load the entire SQLite db into a pandas data frame, update the values in the data frame and then update the entire SQlite db from the data frame at once?

Comment: Use `executemany`

Comment: make url a primary key or index.